# i can't save items in local storage in react js

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I created a to-do application in Reactjs and saved the object that contains data in local storage but the issue is after reloading the page the array that contains items in local storage gets reset and becomes empty again

home component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Form from "./Form"
import TodoList from "./TodoList"
import { useState } from 'react';


function Home() {
const [inputText,setInputText] = useState("")
const [Todos,setTodos] = useState([])
localStorage.setItem('Todos', JSON.stringify(Todos));
const localStorageData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Todos"))

const Tasks = localStorageData.map(function(i){
 return <TodoList value={i.text}/>
})
return(
<div>
<Form inputText={inputText} setInputText={setInputText} Todos={Todos} setTodos={setTodos}/>
{Tasks}
</div>
)

}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
import React, { Component, useEffect } from 'react';
import Form from "./Form"
import TodoList from "./TodoList"
import { useState } from 'react';


function Home() {
const [inputText,setInputText] = useState("")
const [Todos,setTodos] = useState([])
//useEffect(function (){}, []) this hook takes function as its first argument and an array/dependency as 
//which if the [] arrray is empty it runs once, meaning on initial render
useEffect(() => {
  const previousData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Todos"));
  setTodos(previousData);
},[])
//and if something changes in the dependency's value in this case inputText the function that is passed as the first argument runs each time
useEffect(() => {
 localStorage.setItem('Todos', JSON.stringify(Todos));
}, [inputText])



const Tasks = localStorageData.map(function(i){
 return <TodoList value={i.text}/>
})
return(
<div>
<Form inputText={inputText} setInputText={setInputText} Todos={Todos} setTodos={setTodos}/>
{Tasks}
</div>
)

}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 2):

Your line:

```
localStorage.setItem('Todos', JSON.stringify(Todos));
```

is resetting the local storage and setting items once again on refresh. You can avoid this with simple IF statement to check if localStorage is empty and then assign items:

```
if(!localStorage.getItem("Todos") || JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Todos")).length === 0){
 localStorage.setItem('Todos', JSON.stringify(Todos));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is behavior is happening because you're trying to set the local storage value in the root of your component. If what you want is to setLocalStorage every time Todos change, you could either use the useEffect hook or a wrapper for the set function.

Also, you need to initialize your Todos state using the localStorage value, so that it isn't set to an empty array when you reload the page, as such:

```
const [Todos, setTodos] = useState(
    // if the value returned by JSON.parse is nullish, intialize as an empty array
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Todos')) ?? [],
);
```

With useEffect (this will run a side-effect function whenever any variable inside the dependency array changes, in this case, Todos):

```
useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('Todos', JSON.stringify(Todos));
}, [Todos]);
```

With wrapper function (instead of using the built-in setTodos function you call a wrapper that sets both Todos and the local storage values):

```
const setTodosWithLocalStorage = useCallback(newTodos => {
    localStorage.setItem('Todos', JSON.stringify(newTodos));
    setTodos(newTodos);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add view or remove data in Local Storage**

- const textForStorage = " Hello World. ";
- localStorage.setItem("my-text", textForStorage);
- const textFormStorage = localStorage.getItem("my-key");
- localStorage.removeItem("my-text");
- const person = { firstName: "john", lasName: "alex" };
- localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(person));
- localStorage.clear();